# How to provide the fold change value of a group of biological replicates?

Tags: bioinformatics

I want to visualize relative gene expression with barplot + error bars after qPCR analysis. I was asked to use the log2FoldChange values for the barplots, where each bar should summarize 3 values (the biological replicates).
I calculate the delta delta CT (ddCT) as dCT(treated) - dCT(control).
The fold change is calculated as 2^ddCT.

From which value can I calculate the mean for the representative value of all three replicates (and should I take arithmetic or geometric mean)? Should I take the average of the ddCTs first and then exponentiate it for Fold change? Or can I take the average of the 3 fold changes?

| condition | ddCT | Fold change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| untreated | 0 | 1 |
| treatment1 | -0.4997 | 0.7072 |
| treatment2 | -3.8894 | 0.0674 |
| untreated | 0 | 1 |
| treatment1 | 1.00437 | 2.0060 |
| treatment2 | -1.485 | 0.3570 |
| untreated | 0 | 1 |
| treatment1 | -2.0324 | 0.2444 |
| treatment2 | -0.4631 | 0.7253 |

Answer (score 1):

Quantitative polymerase chain reaction (qPCR) data are initially reported as the number of cycles, $C_T$, needed for a specific PCR-amplified nucleic-acid product to exceed a threshold quantity. Delta-$C_T$ (d$C_T$) values represent differences in $C_T$ between the analyte of interest and an analyte thought to be independent of the experimental conditions (like a "housekeeping" gene), to try to control for differences in starting material between samples. Delta-delta-$C_T$ (dd$C_T$) values can be differences in d$C_T$ between experimental treatments and a control, used to report the effects of the treatments on the analyte of interest.

You generally want to do calculations of means and estimate confidence intervals in a scale where errors are fairly symmetrically distributed above and below the mean. From that perspective it's best to work in original units related to $C_T$ values. The exponentiation needed to translate $C_T$-related values to fold changes can lead to very large skew. If you want to report confidence levels in terms of fold change, first calculate the confidence levels in the $C_T$-related scales and only exponentiate at the end.

Although you have used your control condition as a basis with dd$C_T$ of 0, don't forget to show error bars based on its d$C_T$ values, to give your audience an estimate of reproducibility. Also evaluate whether the control nucleic acid used to get the d$C_T$ values is itself unaffected by your experimental treatments. Otherwise, apparent results on your analyte of interest might instead represent effects of your experimental manipulations on that control analyte.

Comment: Thank you! So I better calculate the average of the three replicates on the ddCT (or dCT) level, right? But how can the arithmetic mean be the right choice for values that are on a log scale? The average of 21, 22, 23 would be 22 then, although there is DOUBLE the amount of RNA in CT=21 than in CT=22...Or should I take geometric mean (21,9 in this case)?

Comment: @vhio working directly in the (d)dCT scale is OK, particularly for making comparisons among treatments. Many statistical tests assume that the distribution of errors in mean-value estimates approaches a normal distribution (at least in some limit). That assumption generally holds much better in (d)dCT scales rather than in the exponentiated scales. If you work in the (d)dCt scale and then exponentiate, you are reporting the _[geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of the RNA values_. I don't see much point in evaluating the geometric mean of the ddCT values.